# How to display a firebase "row" that has two columns in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm creating an assignment tracker app with Ionic 2/Typescript and using Firebase as the database. The home page is a list of assignments in the database. When the user adds a new assignment, it takes 2 inputs from the user (title and date due) and saves them to one entry in the database with no issue. I can't figure out how to get the entry displaying back in the app though? I did have it working perfectly with one user input and an alert instead of a separate page for adding, the separate page is where it went downhill.

I'm not sure if I'm adding wrong or displaying wrong or both - any help or advice would be really appreciated!

Typescript code for when user saves a new assignment:

```
saveItem(){
 var assignment = {
  title : this.title,
  due : this.due,
 }

this.assignments.push({
           assignment,
        });
}
```

Ionic code for adding new:

```
<form (submit) = "saveItem()" >
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Assignment Title</ion-label>
  <ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>Date</ion-label>
   <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="due" name="due"></ion-datetime>   
 </ion-item>

 <div padding>
  <button type="submit" color="primary" block >Save</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

Ionic code for displaying list:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let a of assignments | async" (click)="showOptions(a.$key, a.title, a.due)">
  {{a.assignment}}
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And this is how it shows up in the database:
[testentry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afVZR.png)

Comment: Can you show us your `on("child_added")` callback?

Comment: is that for updating the ion-list or for something else? The async meant I didn't need one initially, is that where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Oh, yes. You need to use `on("child_added")` to get the latest added values and update your list. `this.assigments` is a reference to the firebase database, right? or is it just an array?

Comment: Yeah it's a reference to the database! Where should I put the on("child_added")?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new global array and use it to store the assignments to be shown. Declare you new global array as `assignmentsList`. Leave your `saveItem` function unchanged, but make those changes:

In your view, change this:

`*ngFor="let a of assignments | async"`

to this:

`*ngFor="let a of assignmentsList | async"`

On your class, you'll need to add a `on("child_added")`, something like this:
Inside your constructor:

```
this.assignmentsList = [];
this.assignments.on("child_added", snapshot => {
  this.assignmentsList.push(snapshot.val());
});
```

The above code will fetch all assignments that were previously added to Firebase as well as the newly added.

Let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: I added all of this in but I'm getting an error with "on" in the constructor, it's telling me it "does not exist on type "FirebaseListObservable<any>"? Any reference to assignments in my code is for "assignments: FirebaseListObservable<any>" so I don't think I can take that out - can I?

Comment: Oh, okay. You're using AngularFire, right? You don't need the `on` function then (I think). The `assignments` array should be updating automatically. How are you declaring your `this.assignments` object?